# Docker image does not run with specified Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.12-slim-buster
FROM aaftio/face_recognition
RUN pip install redis
RUN pip3 install glob2

RUN pip install face_recognition
COPY ./worker.py /worker.py
COPY ./rediswq.py /rediswq.py

CMD  python3 worker.py
```

I build the image and run my image with `docker run -it {image_id}`,
but I see errors from python app - It complains about f-strings syntax as it is supported since python 3.6 I address that it uses some older python.

I debugged and get python version it printed 1.19.0

The error:

```
      File "worker.py", line 14
    for filename in glob.iglob(f"/root/divisions/{division_number}/" + '**/*.*', recursive=True):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I debugged and executed `whereis python3` and the output is

```
python3: /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.5-config /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.4m /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.4-config /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/share/python3
```

Comment: what is the actual error message? when testing with python 3.7.12 (via pyenv?), do you get the same errors?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors when I run my python app without Docker. When I dockerize my python app like above and try to run it complains about f-string syntax. I debugged it and at beginning of code I put simple f-string and it complained there.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, start a shell inside the docker image (I don't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head but you should be able to google it). Then run `python3 -v` in that shell. Does the output match what you expect? If you do `python3 worker.py` in the docker shell, does it give the same errors?

Comment: error text and the f-string in question would be helpful

Comment: Updated my post. It does not even show python3.7

Comment: In your `CMD`, what happens if you use `python` rather than `python3`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did and it shows Python 3.4.9 :/

Comment: @C.Nivs same error :(

Comment: Hmm that is very strange. I created a hello world app and used prepared a Dockerfile with python 3.7 and it ran fine.

Comment: @memoricab The problem is in the way you have defined the dockerfile and tried to create a multi stage build. Your end docker container will always be based of the last docker container you have used in your Dockerfile for you it is `aaftio/face_recognition` which uses `Python 3.4.9` and not `python:3.7.12-slim-buster` which uses `Python 3.7.12`. Reference for multi-stage docker builds - here

Comment: Omg yes, that's the problem. Could you please send this as answer, so I could accept. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @kartikkillawala Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the way you have defined the Dockerfile

While creating a docker multi stage build, your final container will always be based off the last docker container you have referenced

So in your case it will be `aaftio/face_recognition` which uses `Python 3.4.9` and not `python:3.7.12-slim-buster` which uses `Python 3.7.12`

Reference for docker multi stage build - [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

You can try something like this

```
FROM aaftio/face_recognition as intermediate
RUN pip install face_recognition


FROM python:3.7.12-slim-buster

#Copy the python installed libraries from intermediate container
#COPY --from=intermediate face_recognition

RUN pip install redis
RUN pip3 install glob2
COPY ./worker.py /worker.py
COPY ./rediswq.py /rediswq.py

CMD  python3 worker.py
```